# Are the rules written in stone?

Tags: discussion

Is there a notion of revisiting meta topics and problems, or are they written in stone, and once discussed they never change?

If so, do we have to live with all the bad decisions?

<sub>Note: I don't want to give examples. Think of this as a meta meta-question.</sub>

Comment: Any answer would be hand wavy without examples. What policies do you want to talk about?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker just a shot in the dark, but possibly [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278118/why-does-stackoverflow-continue-to-willfully-lie-about-my-user-activity) would be an example.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Does it depend on the (type of) policy? If so, I would love to see a detailed answer on the categories and their treatment.

Comment: @bluefeet: yes, that gave me the idea. please **don't** think this question as my way to solve that problem! that *wasn't* my intention.

Comment: Meta would be a pretty quiet place if SE used 10 stone tablets retrieved from a mountain.  We try to get along by *consensus*.  Which does require listening to each other, you can use meta as a soapbox but that certainly doesn't guarantee everybody will see it your way.

Comment: @HansPassant: I understand your metaphor, but as you know you can also make progress by creating new tablets all the time. I feel I have a decent question here but of course this might have been discussued or trivial to someone else. I just observe the behaviour here and I can tell you it isn't trivial to me.  p.s.: Your soapbox simile makes me think you misunderstood my intentions. you're also welcomed to *listen*.

Comment: The issue that bluefeet linked to is in some way beyond being a "rule", since it requires programming support to change. For feature requests like that, see [Can we re request features that were declined a sufficient while ago?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89026) and some of the questions linked to that.

Comment: Put forth your ideas, back them up with concrete examples, respond openly and without hostility to those who question them, and accept that not everybody feels decisions you consider "bad" to be such.  Unless you want to require downvoters to have to leave a comment, because that's effing stupid and everybody who wants that is a big old dumbhead.

Comment: @Will: ???. Please *explain* why you left this comment. Which of my utterances made you write this?

Comment: I'm saying any argument is fine, except for the downvoter comment one.  That one **is** set in stone.  Didn't mean to make it seem like you have suggested it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it is discussed once and there are new facts and or developments that sets that one original question in a different/new perspective that can't  also be addressed by answering the original question, by all means do start a new question and explain why the new question sets it apart from the older question.

If your only purpose is to do a discussion all over again on an already established status-quo and nothing new to add except to have extra attention for your or a particular point-of-view , by all means **NO**, don't do that. We better handle some cv-pls requests or do some review tasks instead...